# Grails entity change my tables and create new

Tags: mysql, grails, entity

I have 2 tables, with relation one to many.

I create 2 entity's on this tables. But when I try get data created third table and in exist tables add new fields.

My tables

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Question` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `answer` (
    `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `QuestionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Answer` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `IsCorrect` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `FK_Question` (`QuestionID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Question` FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionID`) REFERENCES `question` (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

My entity's

```java
class Answer {

    int id

    String answer

    boolean isCorrect
    static belongsTo = Question

    static constraints = {
    }

}

class Question {

    int id
    String question
    List<Answer> answers
    static hasMany = [answers : Answer]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

After using grails, change in mysql tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE `question` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Question` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `version` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

CREATE TABLE `answer` (
    `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `QuestionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Answer` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `IsCorrect` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `version` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `is_correct` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `FK_Question` (`QuestionID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Question` FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionID`) REFERENCES `question` (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=32;

CREATE TABLE `question_answer` (
    `question_answers_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `answer_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `answers_idx` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `FK561DF237111171E9` (`answer_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK561DF237111171E9` FOREIGN KEY (`answer_id`) REFERENCES `answer` (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

So, how fix this problem? Why grails change my tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declared:

```
static belongsTo = Question
```

But this makes the relation unidirectional, since you cannot query this belongsTo. In this case Grails will use a join table. If you don't want the join table, you need to make it bidirectional, by declaring:

```
static belongsTo = [question: Question]
```

More information about this [here](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com.br/2010/10/grails-one-to-many-mapping-with-foreign.html).

Comment: After declaration [question: Question], third table didn't create, but have a few problem create new fields in table answer as show above and when try get data from answer got exception                                                                        Caused by UnhandledException: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [ua.home.testknowledge.Question#0]

Comment: Yes it's help me. But why entity's create new fields in my tables and how fix problem with fields. Why they didn't use my fields?

Comment: Grails follow the convention of converting camelCase in underlines in your database. That's why isCorrect becomes is_correct. I suggest you to take a look in the [GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) docs, to understand how the database mapping works. To adjust your attributes, check [table and column names](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#tableAndColumnNames).